# return response.end doesn't work as expected in node.js

Tags: node.js

return res.end() doesn't return from the createServer method. Also, the output is printed twice.

While i don't do any res.write and instead console.log(..) followed by return only, things work fine. It is only after i try to send response to the client using res.write(..) and return res.end() that return stmt doesn't work as expected.

```
const http=require('http');
const server=http.createServer((req,res)=>{
                  if(req.url==='/more'){
                    console.log('Inside /more');
                    res.write("Inside /more");
                    return res.end();

                   }

                  if(req.url==='/message'){
                    console.log('Inside /message');
                    res.write("Inside /message");
                    res.end();
                    return;
                    }

                  console.log("Outside All");
                  res.write("Outside All");
                  res.end();
               });

server.listen(5000);
```

> with url: "http://localhost:5000/more" console output is: Inside /more 
>                      Outside All 
> Browser output is: Inside /more

I expect the console output to be: Inside /more only. Any code outside the first 'if' should not execute as if contains return res.end().

> with url: "http://localhost:5000/xyz"  console output is: Outside All 
>                       Outside All 
>   Browser output is: Outside All

Don't know why Outside All is printed twice in console.

Comment: why you are not using express?

Comment: Rahul....just trying to understand the raw node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is ok just like you expect. This is because of the browser behavior which is making the second request for `favicon.ico`. If you make this request thru postman, for example, there will be only one console log.